# Smartface convert json

Tags: smartface.io

My codes is as follows. I want to get the data in JSON. But the data is coming as XML. How can I solve this problem?

```
var wc = new SMF.Net.WebClient({       
    URL:"http://192.168.41.179/TestWS/ws.asmx/myComments",
    httpMethod:"GET",
    requestHeaders: ["content-type", "application/json"],
    onSyndicationSuccess: function(e) {
        deger = wc.response;
    }
});
wc.run(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. We need to use WebAPI for this.